# Define a value such that vector is an eigenvector of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix: $\begin{pmatrix}
a & 6 & 3\\
-1 & a & 1 \\
1 & 2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

What is "a" value  such that vector $\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
-1 \\
-2 
\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector

I composed an polynomial of it: $a λ^2 - 4 a λ - 8 a - λ^3 + 4 λ^2 + 4 λ - 16 = 0$ and a plot but I still can't find that a. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

From the equation $Av=\lambda v$,

$$a^2-6-6=\lambda a$$

$$-a-a-2=-\lambda\tag{1}$$

$$a-2+2=-2\lambda \tag{2}$$

I would then solve the simultaneous equation $(1)$ and $(2)$. I will leave the rest as an exercise including verifying if the $a$ found indeed work.